# Android TextEdit Words Suggestion List

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-listview, android-edittext

i am making a Gestures detect application, on which i type and detect the words from my library, i want to use Words Suggestion List. that fetches words from my database and display them in temporary area from where i can select my desired word. i am attaching a sample image along with the post. please help me in this regard.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html).

Comment: yes i used it but what i want to display Suggestion List in this way not as it appear normally .

Comment: Sorry I can't understand what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think modifying your textview InputType would achieve what you want.

```
<TextView 
android:inputType="textAutoComplete" />
```

More info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType